# how to set cron user wise in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have set cron that runs stock updation for users, Now I have user wise setting if stock updation is set to 'Yes' by user than only that cron should run for particular user.

I have googled it but could not find any solution

Any reference or advice are welcome.

Comment: Wrap the code inside the cron with an if statement with the setting maybe?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel it's bad practice to put logic in cron. Use commands and scheduler for that. This problem is common, but another approach that is simple is filter which users need an update in the command.

```
class UpdateStocks extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'update:stocks';

    public function handle()
    {
        User::where('update_stock', 'Yes')->get()->each(function(User $user) {
            // run logic to update the stock
        })
    }
```

Put the command in the scheduler.

```
$schedule->call(new UpdateStocks)->daily();
```

Comment: Thanks @martin. I will try this solution

Comment: If anything blocks you in this, i'm pretty sure i can help you with a solution.

Comment: Sure . That's very helpful

Comment: Can I do with below scheduler command -->
 
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('update:stocks')
            ->daily();
    }